# configuring HTMLPurifier to disable hyperlinks

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am trying to disable hyperlinks and show them in plain text using HTMLPurifier but I did not get right. Here is my code:

```
$html ='<a href="http://www.localhost.com/">link</a><b>test</b>';
 require_once 'include/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
                        $Config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
                        $Config->set('AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI', true);
                        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
                        $html = $purifier->purify($html);                   
                        echo $html;
```

The current output is:

```
    <a href="http://www.localhost.com/">link</a><b>test</b>
```

What is the problem? The output should be:

```
<a>link</a> (http://www.localhost.com/)<b>test</b>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you're not passing the config object to the HTML Purifier constructor, so it doesn't work.

Second problem: you haven't actually told HTML Purifier to remove href attributes from a tags. I'm not really sure what will happen to DisplayLinkURI if you do that though.